# Intersecting zset and set not working in Redis

Tags: redis, set-intersection

I have the following two sets and I'm trying to intersect them and store the result:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> smembers out2
1) "judy_1"

127.0.0.1:6379> zrange dateset 0 -1 withscores
 1) "judy_4"
 2) "118903"
  ....
19) "judy_1"
20) "137967"
```

You can see "judy_1" is present in both the set and the zset (w/the associated score of 137967). I want to intersect the "out2" and "dateset" to be left with "judy_1" and score.

I attempt to perform this and store the result in "result", but it's returning an empty set.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zinterstore result 2 out2 dataset
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379>
127.0.0.1:6379> smembers result
(empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange result 0 -1
(empty list or set)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is what you get for coding 12 hours ... the error is datAset vs datEset. = [

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works at my end..

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> sadd out2 judy_1
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zadd dataseet 118903 judy_4
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zadd dataseet 137967 judy_1
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zrange dataseet 0 -1 withscores
1) "judy_4"
2) "118903"
3) "judy_1"
4) "137967"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zinterstore result 2 out2 dataseet
ZRANGE  result 0 -1
1) "judy_1"
```

which version you are using?

Comment: Strange -- I'm using Python (import Redis) to send the commands.

Comment: Do you mind doing an object encoding <set> on your sets so I can compare them to mine ... ?

Comment: how you are encoding? are you encoding it and then storing it in redis?